# Redirect network traffict through different gateway depending on the file type

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming

i have a local network, and i have various wan conections, i want to redirect the traffic to a selected gateway depending on the file extession, example:

Redirect html xhtml css files to gateway1, .mp4 .zip .rar files to gateway2 and so on...

This way i can optimize my network to always have a stable web browsing, and having a dedicated line for big downloads.

Thanks beforehand, any suggestion will be appreciated (:, if you know a way to achieve this filtering using the file size instead of file extession (if posible) let me know.

PS: i was trying to achieve this with the router configuration but it seems to not be posibble, and was able to achieve this using isa on windows but i want a linux solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a combination of technologies. First stateful packet inspection to examine the contents or payload then a filter rule to redirect. Another method might be to use a proxy server such as squid

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to configure Squid to achieve this?... or know about any tutorial to do it??

Comment: I haven't read the entire document but it looks like this type of configuration is what you are looking for. http://freecode.com/articles/configuring-a-transparent-proxywebcache-in-a-bridge-using-squid-and-ebtables

Comment: No worries, I haven't configured and used squid in such a long time however here are the configuration directives you are looking for...

**acl aclname req_mime_type** & **acl aclname req_header header-name**

The [reference](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/) for the various squid configuration directives

Comment: ive found a solution based on what you told me, i just had to send to the cache_peer upstream proxy ...